How to show the message box after progressbar UI run finished in correctly?
I'm practicing with the progressBar to separate the UI and logic with C# WindowsForm.(trying impelement DIP)
I use async-await to prevent the UI thread freezing while thr progress is running.
However, I've noticed a strange issue on the GUI. The problem is that the tool displays the message box before the progress bar finishes running. Here is the GIF link below to illustrate my question.
Code_1 GIF
Code_1
UI layer:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PracticeProgressBarSeprate
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private ProgressBarLogic progressLogic;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
            progressLogic = new ProgressBarLogic(100);
            progressLogic.ProgressChanged += ProgressLogic_ProgressChanged;
            progressLogic.ProgressCompleted += ProgressLogic_ProgressCompleted;
        }

        private void btnStartTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStartTest.Enabled = false;
            progressLogic.StartProgress();
        }

        private void ProgressLogic_ProgressChanged(object sender, int currentValue)
        {
            progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                progressBar1.Value = (int)Math.Round((double)currentValue / 100 * 100);
            }));
        }

        private void ProgressLogic_ProgressCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Progress finished!");
                btnStartTest.Enabled = true;   
            }));
            
        }
    }
}

Logic layer:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PracticeProgressBarSeprate
{
    class ProgressBarLogic
    {
        private int totalSteps;
        private int currentStep;

        public event EventHandler<int> ProgressChanged;
        public event EventHandler ProgressCompleted;

        public ProgressBarLogic(int totalSteps)
        {
            this.totalSteps = totalSteps;
            this.currentStep = 0;
        }

        public async void StartProgress()
        {
            currentStep = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < totalSteps; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
                currentStep++;
                OnProgressChanged(currentStep);
            }
            OnProgressCompleted();
        }

        protected virtual void OnProgressChanged(int currentValue)
        {
            ProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, currentValue);
        }

        protected virtual void OnProgressCompleted()
        {
            ProgressCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

In order to debug the issue, I add the debug point on OnProgressChanged(currentStep);
I found the root cause is that when the value of currentStep reaches 100, although the UI progress bar hasn't finished running, it meets the condition to exit the for-loop.
As a result, it proceeds to execute the next function OnProgressCompleted(); and show the message box.
My current method to solve this issue is that add the Task.await(1000) before the OnProgressCompleted(); in Logic layer.(The effect that I want is show in Code_2 GIF as below)
Code_2
But it seems not a good method.
Can anyone tell me what reason cause the Code 1 issue and how to fix this issue smartly?

Is this .NET Framework or .NET Core Framework?

@ Karen Payne  I use windowsForm (.NET Framework)

Okay, I was going to recommend using IProgress if using .NET Core but its not available in .NET Framework.

Thanks for your replyment. Could I ask you why use Iprogress can fix it in .NET Core?
